# Segmentation fault after while loop that follows malloc

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am trying to create a 2d array dynamically, then open a txt file and copy each lenient my 2d array. Then save this array back to my main. I keep running into a segmentation error. Any suggestions how to do fix this code?
BTW i think the problem stars after the 2nd time while loop occurs...

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    char **randomArrayofStrings(){
        char **twoArray=null;
        int rows=50;
        int col=20;
        i=0;
        FILE *file=null;
        int messageSize=50;//this is number is trivial
        file = fopen("somefile.txt","r");
        twoArray= malloc(rows*sizeof(char*));
        for(i=0;i<col;i++)
        {
             twoArray[i]=malloc(rows*sizeof(char));
             strcpy(twoArray[i], "some random word");
        }
        while(!feof(file))
        {
             fgets(dArray[i],messageSize, file);
             strtok(dArray[i], "\n");
             i++;
        }   
        return twoArray;
    }


    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        char **localArray=null;
        localArray=randomArrayofStrings();
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)//20 is just a random number
             printf("Strings: %s", localArray[i]);
    }
```

Comment: `return twoArray` -> `return twoArray;` (missing `;`).

Answer (score 2):

As I see, in your function `randomArrayofStrings` loop `for` goes through columns "i cols in your code. So, you allocate array of pointers first and consider it as `cols` and then in a loop you allocate `rows`.

And after `malloc` check the value that was returned and do not use the pointer if it is NULL after memory allocation.

To free allocated memory, use the inverted sequence - free all `rows` in a loop and than free `cols` once. E.g.:

```cpp
        for(i=0;i<col;i++){
            free(twoArray[i]);
        }
        free(twoArray);
        twoArray = NULL;
```

**EDIT:**

And also, to use `malloc` and `free` you need `#include <stdlib.h>`, and `#include <string.h>` for `strcopy`, `int i=0;` should be instead of `i=0;`, and correct null value for pointers is `NULL`.

And what is `dArray`? I do not see the declaration or definition? Dou you mean `twoArray`?

**EDIT2:**

The following is my version of your program:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **randomArrayofStrings(){
    char **twoArray=NULL;
    char * ptr = NULL;
    int rows=50; // this will be also message size
    int cols=20;
    int i=0;
    FILE *file=NULL;
    file = fopen("somefile.txt","r");
    if( file == NULL )
        return NULL;
    twoArray = (char**) malloc(cols * sizeof(char*));
    if(twoArray == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    for(i=0;i<cols;i++)
    {
        twoArray[i] = (char*)malloc(rows*sizeof(char));
        if(twoArray[i] == NULL)
            return NULL;
        strcpy(twoArray[i], "some random word");
    }
    i = 0; // reset counter
    while(!feof(file))
    {
        fgets(twoArray[i], rows, file);
        ptr = strchr(twoArray[i],'\n');
        if( ptr )
            *ptr = '\0';
        else
            twoArray[i][rows-1] = '\0';
        i++;
        if( i >= cols)
            break;
    }   
    fclose(file);
    return twoArray;
}

void freeMy2dArray(char **twoArray, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < n; i++){
         free(twoArray[i]);
    }
    free(twoArray);
    twoArray = NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    char **localArray=NULL;
    localArray = randomArrayofStrings();
    if( localArray == NULL )
        return 1;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)//20 is just a random number
        printf("Strings: %s\n", localArray[i]);
    freeMy2dArray(localArray, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not suppossed to `free()` `twoArray` inside `randomArrayofStrings()`. You have to free them inside `main()`, once you're done with using the allocated memeory.

That said, the way you're using `sizeof(localArray)` in `main()` is wrong. You have to use the exact value you did use to poupulate `twoArray`.

Comment: i dont understand how I can free(twoArray) if once I copy its address to localArray, ( from my noob knowledge) main has no way of accessing and free twoArray

Comment: @RT89 OK then, if the above is true, why're you returning the `twoArray`? It should not be usable in `main()`, right? Well, it __is__ usable and valid inside `main()` untill and unless you `free()` it. Dynamic memory allocation scope is global and as long as you have a _valid_ pointer to access that, it is fine.

Comment: @RT89 You're aloocating memory and returning the pointer `twoArray` which is collected in `localArray`. so, you can use `localArray` to access the memory, same way as you would have used `twoArray`.

Comment: if i understand you correctly then I  could add free(twoArray) after this line: (localArray=randomArrayofStrings();)

Comment: @RT89 not likely. see my above comment.

Comment: @RT89 First you have to free each element in `localArray`, then `localArray` itself.